# django not receiving correct response? in front

Tags: javascript, django

### overview

When you press the 'like!' button, there is processing to feed back to the front screen via server processing (create or delete).

No error when creating. Feedback is fine too.
I get an error when deleting and the feedback doesn't work.

The content of the error seems to be that json cannot be received correctly.

The creation process and deletion process are almost the same, and the records are also registered and deleted in the database. So the processing is exactly the same.

What's causing this?
It seems so simple, but...

### detail

[image]
[image]

```py
# model
class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    note = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = ArticlesQuerySet.as_manager()

    @staticmethod
    def with_state(user_id: int) -> QuerySet:
        return Articles.objects.annotate(
                likes_cnt=Count('likes'),
                liked_by_me=Case(
                    When(id__in=Likes.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).values('articles_id'),
                         then=1),
                    default=0,
                    output_field=IntegerField()
                )
            )

class Likes(models.Model):
    articles = models.ForeignKey('Articles', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['articles_id', 'user_id'],
                name='articles_user_unique'
            )
        ]
```

```py
# views.py
class LikesCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return_value = None
        try:
            Likes.objects.create(user_id=kwargs['user_id'], articles_id=kwargs['article_id'])
            article = Articles.with_state(kwargs['user_id']).get(pk=kwargs['article_id'])
            return_value = json.dumps({'likes_cnt': article.likes_cnt, 'liked_by_me': article.liked_by_me})
            print(f'LikesCreateView return_value[{type(return_value)}]: ', return_value)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            logging.critical('There was an access from an unauthorized user account')
        except Articles.DoesNotExist:
            logging.critical('An unauthorized article was accessed')

        return HttpResponse(return_value, status=201)


class LikesDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return_value = None
        try:
            Likes.objects.filter(user_id=kwargs['user_id'], articles_id=kwargs['article_id']).delete()
            article = Articles.with_state(kwargs['user_id']).get(pk=kwargs['article_id'])
            return_value = json.dumps({'likes_cnt': article.likes_cnt, 'liked_by_me': article.liked_by_me})
            # TODO: When creating, the front receives json correctly, but when it becomes delete, an accident occurs ...why?
            print(f'LikesDeleteView return_value[{type(return_value)}]: ', return_value)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            logging.critical('There was an access from an unauthorized user account')
        except Articles.DoesNotExist:
            logging.critical('An unauthorized article was accessed')

        return HttpResponse(return_value, status=204)
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<div class="col-sm">
  <h2>nice! function</h2>
  <h6>'like' function</h6>
  {% for article in articles %}
        :
    <button
        type="button"
        class="like_toggle btn btn-light"
        data-article-id="{{ article.id }}"
        data-liked-by-me="{{ article.liked_by_me }}"
    >nice!<span>({{ article.likes_cnt }})</span></button>
        :
  {% endfor %}
  <a href="{% url 'vnm:article_create' %}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" role="button">post!</a>
</div>

  :

    <script lang="js">
        const likeToggles = document.getElementsByClassName('like_toggle');
        for (let i = 0; i < likeToggles.length; i++) {
            likeToggles[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
                const articleId = likeToggles[i].dataset.articleId
                const likedByMe = parseInt(likeToggles[i].dataset.likedByMe)
                console.log(`article_id: ${articleId} を User: {{ user.id }} ${likedByMe}）`);
                const userId = {{ user.id }}
                if (!userId) {
                    location.href = myurl.login
                }

                const createOrDelete = likedByMe ? 'delete' : 'create'
                console.log(`createOrDelete: ${createOrDelete}`)
                fetch(`${myurl.base}likes/${createOrDelete}/${userId}/${articleId}/`, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        "X-CSRFToken": Cookies.get('csrftoken')
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({"status": "requested from javascript."})
                    }
                )
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(json => {
                    console.log("return json is : ", json)
                    likeToggles[i].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = `(${json.likes_cnt})`
                    likeToggles[i].dataset.likedByMe = json.liked_by_me
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error('There has been a problem with your fetch operation:', error)
                })
            })
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you return `status=204` in `LikesDeleteView` which is the status for

`204 No Content: The server successfully processed the request, and is not returning any content.`

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

```
return HttpResponse(return_value, status=204)
```

Should be 200 like in `LikesCreateView`

Comment: oh! I took solved!
In fact, it is this modification that returned this status code. And I misunderstood the meaning of 204.
I change 200OK